# What does Docker run --storage-opt size=XYZ means?

Tags: docker, storage, docker-container

Docker run cli command has an option `--storage-opt` used like this:

```
docker run --storage-opt size=XYZ ....nginx
```

Does the "`XYZ`" size specified above refer to the CoW layer or the total size of base image and CoW layer as discussed in [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers) ?

Answer (score 2):

From: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-storage-driver-options-per-container

```
docker run -it --storage-opt size=120G fedora /bin/bash
```

> This (size) will allow to set the container rootfs size to 120G at
>   creation time. This option is only available for the devicemapper,
>   btrfs, overlay2, windowsfilter and zfs graph drivers. For the
>   devicemapper, btrfs, windowsfilter and zfs graph drivers, user cannot
>   pass a size less than the Default BaseFS Size. For the overlay2
>   storage driver, the size option is only available if the backing fs is
>   xfs and mounted with the pquota mount option. Under these conditions,
>   user can pass any size less then the backing fs size.

Comment: Is that the size of the CoW layer of the rootfs, or does it include the size of the rootfs from the image layers?

Comment: The size of the rootfs.

Comment: With a unionfs, the size of the rootfs is ambiguous.

Comment: It's the visible size of the root filesystem of the container when you run `df`, for example.  It's has nothing to do with the size of the CoW layers.

Comment: " For the devicemapper, btrfs, windowsfilter and zfs graph drivers, user cannot pass a size less than the Default BaseFS Size." - what is this Default BaseFS size and why the restriction?

Comment: @ben The default sizes are specified with the --storage-option to the docker daemon.  See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#storage-driver-options